# R: picture file not supported in a webscrape

Tags: r, image

I'm new to here. the ambient is R, I structured a simple web-scrape with `rvest` to pick up some images. When I save it into my folder it tells me that the file is not supported. Anybody know why?

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://x.yupoo.com/photos/05941188/albums"

imgsrc <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*/img') %>%
  html_attr('src')

download.file(
  paste0(url, imgsrc), destfile = 'myimage.jpg', method="curl"
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, just making sure you know `html_node()` will return only one node vs `html_nodes()` which will return all found nodes. Next, did you look at the contents of `imgsrc` before you used it in the `paste0()`? It's value is `"https://upzip.b0.upaiyun.com/website/4.4.22/imgs/logo_3.png"` so you are — in effect — creating an invalid URL reference to a non-existent resource with the `paste0()`

Comment: thank you for the answer! so for you which would be the exact code to extract one of those images?